# How do I get in ASP.NET framework my current URL

Tags: c#, html, url, razor

How do I get in ASP.NET framework my current URL if I want to use some Razor in my `.cshmt` document?

Maybe history is an idea but I didn't find out how I have to use it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to use `Request.Url.OriginalString` or `Request.Url`

```
@Request.Url.OriginalString  //url with port
@Request.Url  //url without port
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c5t9RE)